# How to determine the type of data in an MPI message?

Tags: mpi

I understand (or I think I do) using `MPI_PROBE()` and `MPI_GET_COUNT()` to determine the source, tag, and size of an `MPI` message.  But it seems natural to me that there should be some way to determine the type of the data in the message as well.  Can it be done?

Comment: This is not how MPI works.

Comment: No, MPI intentionally does not provide such type information and does not mandate type checking, which is why with most MPI implementations you need special tools to detect type mismatches. If you are trying to implement generic messaging on top of MPI, you should look into serialisation solutions such as `protobuf` or ASN.1 (those are just examples, I'm in no way endorsing the use of ASN.1 :)).

Comment: @HristoIliev  Thanks.  Do you have a link discussing this philosophy?  Not that I doubt you.  It just seems to me like this would be a natural capability to have.  I'm wondering what the thinking was.

Comment: I'm sure there are discussions and reasoning somewhere in the archives of the MPI Forum. Without delving into document archaeology, I'd speculate that the thinking is most likely that adding such capability would make the messages larger and slower to transmit, while having the receiver check the receive type against some type signature in the message would make reception slower. Keep in mind that the MPI specification is 26 years old. Good programming practices and type safety are newcomers in the field of HPC :)

Comment: MPI implementations are free to add such information to the transmitted messages and also free to detect type mismatches upon reception, it's just not required by the standard. Nothing prevents you from adding type information as part of the message data or using a self-describing serialisation format.

Comment: You can read more in Chapter 3.3 (page 33) of the [current MPI specification](https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf). _"Additional type information might be added to messages in order to allow the system to detect mismatches between datatype at sender and receiver.  This might be particularly useful in a slower but safer debug mode.  (End of advice to implementors.)"_ (page 36) hints at performance being the reason.

Comment: @HristoIliev   Thanks!  As always, you're a font of knowledge!